# redirection issue with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Following is my requirement.

I'm building a laravel application for the office use.

My colleagues should be able to log in using their work mail and once they successfully logged in they can access learning materials.

imagine i have a co-worker "A" so the HR would send him a mail with the course link let's say https://lms.test/course/abcde

Once "A" clicks on that link login window should appear to enter his work mail.
https://lms.test/login
once he enter his work mail he'll get an email with an OTP. the screen is to enter the otp
https://lms.test/verify

Once A, enters the correct otp then only he should be redirected to the
https://lms.test/course/abcde
and view the course content.

Again imagine hr sends another course link to a different co-worker B. different link, different course
https://lms.test/course/zxcvbn

again the same flow should be followed.

Now then This is what I have currently done so far,

following is my web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\CourseController;
use App\Providers\CustomUserProvider;

Route::get('/login', 'App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('/login', 'App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@login')->name('login.submit');
Route::get('/verify', 'App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@verifyOtpForm')->name('otp.verify');
Route::post('/verify', 'App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@verifyOtp')->name('otp.verify.submit');

Route::middleware(['verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/courses/{path}', [CourseController::class, 'show'])->name('courses.show');
});

Route::get('/courses', function () {
    return view('courses');
})->name('courses');
```

and this is my loginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Providers\CustomUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function showLoginForm(Request $request)
    {
        session(['previous_url' => $request->path()]);

        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email|ends_with:fonterra.com'
    ]);

    $user = app(CustomUserProvider::class)->retrieveByWorkEmail($request->email);

    if ($user) {
        // Generate and send OTP to the user's email
        $otp = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
        app(CustomUserProvider::class)->sendOtpByEmail($user, $otp);

        $request->session()->put('user', [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'otp' => $otp,
            'previous_url' => session('previous_url'), // Store the previous URL in session
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('otp.verify');
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Invalid work email']);
}


    public function verifyOtpForm(Request $request)
    {
        return view('auth.verify-otp');
    }

    public function verifyOTP(Request $request)
{
    $otp = $request->input('otp');
    $user = session('user');

    if ($user && $user['otp'] == $otp) {
        $user['otp_verified'] = true;

        // Add the allowed paths based on verification
        $allowedPaths = ['frhgfdhtrjejt', 'tyuutiuyiuyi']; // Add the allowed paths based on your logic
        $user['allowed_paths'] = $allowedPaths;

        session(['user' => $user]);

        $previousUrl = session('previous_url');

        //dd($previousUrl );

        if ($previousUrl) {
            session()->forget('previous_url'); // Remove the previous URL from session

            if (in_array($previousUrl, $allowedPaths)) {
                return redirect($previousUrl);
            }
        }

        return redirect()->route('courses');
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors(['otp' => 'Invalid OTP']);
    }
}

}
```

below is my VerifyOTP.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class VerifyOTP
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = session('user');
        $path = $request->path();
        $allowedPaths = [
            'abcde',
            'zxcvbn',
        ];

        if (
            (!$user || !isset($user['otp_verified']) || !$user['otp_verified']) ||
            (in_array($path, $allowedPaths) && !in_array($path, $user['allowed_paths']))
        ) {
            return redirect()->route('login')->withErrors(['message' => 'You need to log in first.']);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

in my kernel.php I have,

```
'verified' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyOTP::class,
```

and i have following CustomUser.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

class CustomUser implements Authenticatable
{
    public $email;

    protected $allowed_paths;

    public function getAllowedPaths()
    {
        return $this->allowed_paths;
    }

    public function __construct($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifierName()
    {
        return 'email';
    }

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        // This method is not needed since we are not using passwords
    }

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        // This method is not needed since we are not using remember tokens
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        // This method is not needed since we are not using remember tokens
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        // This method is not needed since we are not using remember tokens
    }
}
```

Then following provider called, CustomUserProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\CustomUser;

class CustomUserProvider implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider
{
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        //
    }

    public function validateCredentials(Authenticatable $user, array $credentials)
    {
        //
    }

    public function retrieveByWorkEmail($email)
    {
        return new CustomUser($email);
    }

    public function sendOtpByEmail($user, $otp)
    {
        Mail::raw("Your OTP is: $otp", function ($message) use ($user) {
            $message->to($user->email)
                ->subject('OTP Login');
        });
    }

    public function retrieveByOtp($otp)
    {
        $user = session('user');

        if ($user && $user['otp'] == $otp) {
            return new CustomUser($user['email']);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        //
    }

    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
        //
    }

    public function updateRememberToken(Authenticatable $user, $token)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Now this is the issue,

When i tried to access https://lms.test/course/abcde directly i'm redirecting to the login form, where i have to enter my work mail.

Once i submit i get the OTP and redirected to enter the otp

But

Even when I enter the correct OTP it redirect me to https://lms.test/course/ not to https://lms.test/course/abcde.... how can i send my user directly to the https://lms.test/course/abcde or https://lms.test/course/zxcvbn (there will be more links) once they verified without sending them to https://lms.test/course/

**EDIT**

This is my CourseController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class CourseController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('courses.index');
    }

    public function show($path)
{
    $user = session('user');

    if ($user && in_array($path, $user['allowed_paths'])) {
        return view('courses.show', compact('path'));
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('message', 'You need to log in first');
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, reading your code it appears that the course code is a parameter to the `/courses/{path}` route.
When you show the login form, you store the url path in the session using the `$request->path()` method which probably does not return the `{path}` parameter.
Try using `getRequestUri()` or something similar instead of `path()`

I hope I was helpful